# struct pointer used from different functions

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the folowing code:

```
struct data
{
  int a;
  int b;
};  

void test2(struct data *my_data)
{
  (*my_data).a=3;

  (*my_data).b=4;
  printf("%d %d\n", (*my_data).a, (*my_data).b);
}

void test(struct data *my_data)
{
  (*my_data).a=1;

  (*my_data).b=2;

  test2(&my_data);
}

int main(void)
{
   struct data my_data;
   struct data *ptr;

   ptr = &my_data;

   my_data.a=0;
   my_data.b=0;
   printf( "%p %p ",&my_data.a, &my_data.b);
   printf("%d %d\n", my_data.a, my_data.b); 

   test(ptr);
   printf( "%p %p ",&my_data.a, &my_data.b);
   printf("%d %d\n", my_data.a, my_data.b); 
   return 0;
}
```

I can't find a way to stop gcc showing me the following:

std.c: In function ‘test’:
std.c:25:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘test2’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
std.c:11:6: note: expected ‘struct data *’ but argument is of type ‘struct data **’

i cannot find a way to use struct in test2(). Do i have to create a pointer to pointer? And if yes should i do it in main?

Answer (score 2):

Statement `test2(&my_data);` in function `test` is causing the problem. Remove `&` from it.

```
test2(my_data);
```

Also cast `&my_data.a` and `&my_data.b` to `void *`.

```
 printf( "%p %p ", (void *)&my_data.a, (void *)&my_data.b);
```

Comment: thank you very much. But why is this happening? This is a pointer to a struct and what i used in main, i use in test2 also. Why is this wrong?

Comment: In `main` you declared `my_data` as `struct data` type but in both of your functions you declared `my_data` as pointer to `struct data` type and hence no need to append `my_data` with `&` in your function `test2`